# Java semaphore/mutex based on filename

Tags: java, multithreading, filesystems, mutex, semaphore

I am developing an immutable key-value store (think of it as a NoSql key-value database) where each node in the system can store multiple keys but value of a particular key is never updated in place i.e we store all the history of values with a corresponding timestamp.

My current setup is as follows:
For each key on a particular node two files (named as key.index & key.data) are created:

1. index file: which stores the B-Tree index based on the timestamp so that old values of the key can be efficiently looked up
2. A data file: This file contains all the different values assigned to same key (every new value is appended to the file, and length of each value is stored in the index)

Also, along with these files a single file is created which stores the list of all the keys currently present in the system.

When my nodes start receiving multiple get/put request for same key, I want my index & data files to be written in atomic way. However, I can not just make the get/put calls of my key-value store `synchronized` because that will even synchronize calls for different keys which is not required. So I need locks based on filenames (as it is unique).

I thought of a approach of using a `ConcurrentHashMap` with filename as key and value as a `ReaderWriterLock` (Using a concurrentHashMap should not be a bottleneck as threads working with different keys can do get/put on that map concurrently). With this approach I can allow multiple get calls to read same file but also make sure that only 1 thread gets an exclusive write access. However, as the load on my system increases each node in my system will have upto 10,000 keys and in that case my ConcurrentHashMap will have to store 20000 lock objects (1 for index file and 1 for data file of each key). I do not think this is a very efficient approach (having 20,000 lock objects in memory).

Edit: A single node means a single physical machine, I never run multiple instances of my app on same machine, hence all syncrhonization can be done from within JVM.

Is there any better way of solving this problem?

Comment: Use a database?

Comment: @assylias: For storing data? No. I am trying to build a NoSql key-value store!

Comment: You said that you are going to have multiple nodes which mean that you will have multiple instance of your app running. If that's the case then simple `synchronized` wont work since you need to synchronize across all instances of you app.

Comment: @tsolakp I forgot to mention that a single machine is considered as one node, I never run multiple instances of my app on same machine. Updated the question!

Comment: Maybe you should look at how they've done it in some opensource KV store. So far you seem to have only thoughts and doubts, not a very good starting point for creating anything.